# Error downloading Packages for mdev update 'Operation timed out'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, timeout, updates, marmalade

I have been using the Marmalade SDK with VS2010 for developing an IOS app for the last few months.

Yesterday I attempted to build my project, (without changing anything since the last time I built it) and started to receive the following errors:

```
Executing: 'c:\marmalade\6.1\s3e\bin\mdev.bat update'
Downloading: http://source.madewithmarmalade.com/packages/6.1/Packages
error: error downloading url: http://source.madewithmarmalade.com/packages/6.1/P
ackages (<urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')>)
c:/Users/Paddy/Desktop/Speedoku/Speedoku.mkb(17) : error: Executing 'c:\marmalad
e\6.1\s3e\bin\mdev.bat update' failed. (return code 1)
FAILED (error code=3)
```

I updated Marmalade to the newest version but the problem is still there.
I have gone to the link in the error and can see that the file is there, so does not seem to be the issue.

I have been scouring throught the Marmalade forums for a solution, but the one or two people who asked the same thing got little or no response. Hopefully somebody on here will be able to help figure out how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a proxy in chrome stopping it from downloading.